# GKE Regional Cluster creation machine types for Northamerica-Northeast1 do not match documentation

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

When reading the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#available), you can read that only `n1` machine types are available in Montreal. However, from the GKE cluster creation form, when selecting a `Regional` cluster, the machine types include `n1`, `n2` and `c2`. Is this a bug? Are those really available in Regional clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, when selecting Regional clusters, all machine types are listed instead of only those available to you. You'll get an error when trying to create that cluster.

Comment: Hi, working in GCP community support here. I confirmed the issue you are describing and I've reproduced it too. This Issue is now, thanks to you, being taking care of and you can track its resolution progress with this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141748811).